# HP Pavillion AMD Radeon 4250 Problem

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

I have the AMD Mobility Radeon HD 4250 graphics card and I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Now it will install my graphics card driver either via the command line or by going to the AMD website and downloading it. I am running the 64-bit version of Ubuntu, but when I install the graphics driver it installs, but then says there was a problem.

When I go to open my Catalyst control center it says that the graphics driver was not installed properly. I did download the 64-bit driver because that is what my computer is a 64 bit machine.

The problem also persists as in I cannot get my compiz to work and also it doesn't show any of the effects I had before I used compiz such as the simple opening and closing effects.

I had to reinstall Ubuntu on my computer after uninstalling the graphics card. I have looked and cannot seem to find anything...I know AMD pulled the plug on the 4,000 series Radeon HD in the Ubuntu 13.04 and up. How can I resolve this issue and get my GPU to work?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **Legacy** Catalyst driver, AMD no longer support the HD2xxx/3xxx/4xxx series cards with newer drivers. By the way I would continue to use the open source radeon drivers, much less pain in my experience (for anything but gaming).

Anyway, the Legacy drivers can be simply installed using `jockey` as far as I know.

Comment: yeah i remember when they pulled the plug  wierd thing is cylon linux will install my graphics driver and everything will work as intended its just with all the compiz effects it gets a little graphically straining..which is why i installed the gnome desktop via the software center on my ubuntu 13.04 and was just gonna try a simple effect or two such as minimize maximize and the menu just coming into view nothing fancy...but i just wonder if clyon which is based from ubuntu 12.04 will take my graphics card then why wont the actually ubuntu take my grapcis card very odd